# How to get an object using a string in Java

Tags: java

I've been trying to make my code more efficient, and I'm stuck on an issue where I have to repeat myself a lot to create 40+ objects (which results in 40+ functions with basically the same code, just different objects and different values). I am wondering if there is a way to make something like this in Java:

```
public void createObject(String objectName) {
    getObject(objectName).setType(ymlFile.getString(objectName + ".type")); 
    // getObject(objectName) would be the object which has the same name as the value of the string objectName
}
```

Currently I have to have basically this code (with more variables) for over 40 objects, so I was wondering if it is possible to be able to retrieve the object by using the value in the string called objectName, thus meaning that I only have to call the method 40 times, instead of having the big block of code 40 times.

Thanks.

EDIT:
No, this isn't to do with YAML (not really anyway, just showing some of the code). My main issue is I need to be able to retrieve objects by using values of a string.

As for examples of the repetitive code, it's basically this:

```
    public void createObject1() {
        object1.setType(type1);
    }
    public void createObject2() {
        object2.setType(type2);
    }
    // etc. for about 40 objects. basically i want to be able to change that to this:
    public void createObject(String objectName) {
        objectName.setType("value"); // so basically, retrieve the object that has the same name as the value of objectName
    }
```

Comment: you can use a map which contains a `string-object` mapping with object name as key and object as value

Comment: Please explain what `objectName` means and what `getObject` needs to do ... or maybe show us an example of the repetitive code that this is supposed to replace.

Comment: Can you show how does your data look like ? Sample data

Comment: Is your question related to [YAML](https://yaml.org/) ?

Comment: After your edit, I'd also say you could use a `Map<String, ?>` or simply an array.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way to do this in an efficient way would be to retrieve the class with ClassLoader and then instantiate the object from class

Comment: You are probably asking about reflection. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374878/using-reflection-to-set-an-object-property. Check the `newInstance()` method of the `Class` class.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

You probably just want to use two arrays to keep track of all objects and types, especially since it's really bad practice to name variables `something1`, `something2` and so on.

So replace your `object` and `type` variables with:

```
YourClass[] objects = new YourClass[40];
Type types = new Type[40];
```

and replace your `creatObject()` methdod with:

```
public void createObject(int index) {
    objects[index].setType(types[index]);
}
```

which you could even loop over like this:

```
// This condition is overkill since both arrays should have the same size,
// but if you plan on doing something different than that, this should work.
for(int i = 0; i < objects.length && i < types.length; i++)
    createObject(i);
```

If you really want to use strings though, you could do the same thing with a `Map<String, YourClass>` and a `Map<String, Type>`.